# VBA import two txt files in the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to import two txt files in the same workbook?

I can import one txt file easily with

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
```

However whenever I add another it just ignores the first txt file.

Many thanks

Comment: Basically it doesn't ignore it. It just somehow overwrites the first established connection with a new one. So the last text file is the only reflected in the file. You can either load it in different sheets or use ADO.

Answer (score 0):

Does it ignore the first text file or does it overwrite it if ActiveSheet doesn't change?

You could explicitly specify the Sheet(s) before the .Add method(s) or, if you wanted both imports on the same sheet, there is a Destination:= parameter which allows you to specify a starting Range.  A reference can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836161(v=office.15).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load both *Text Files* in the same sheet, you can try using ADO.
Something like:

```
Sub conscious()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rec As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection: Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim datasource As String, txtfiles As Variant _
        , txt1 As String, txt2 As String
    txtfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files, *.csv", _
        MultiSelect:=True)
    datasource = Left(txtfiles(1), InStrRev(txtfiles(1), "\"))
    txt1 = "[" & Dir(txtfiles(1)) & "]"
    txt2 = "[" & Dir(txtfiles(2)) & "]"

    Dim sconnect As String
    sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & datasource & _
                ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(,)"";"
    con.Open sconnect

    Dim sqlstr As String
    sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM " & txt1 & _
            "UNION ALL SELECT * FROM " & txt2
    rec.Open sqlstr, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lrow > 1 Then .Range("A2:J" & lrow).ClearContents
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rec
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    rec.Close: con.Close
    Set rec = Nothing: Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Basically this prompts you to select files.
I used a *CSV* file as sample. Adjust to suit.
You can select as many files, but this handles the first 2 files only.
If you need to handle more, you'll have to loop through the selected files. HTH