# Specifying 2 DataSources in SQL SELECT Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, datasource, connection-string

I have an SQL SELECT Query in which i am joining 2 or more different CSV files located in  different folders. I am using ADO in Excel VBA. How do i specify the ADO Connection string's DataSource parameter to accept the 2 different Paths?

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & strDataSource1 &","& strDataSource2 & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM [FILE1.CSV] AS F1 INNER JOIN [FILE2.CSV] AS F2 ON F1.ID = F2.ID
```

Comment: just put the full path name in your query such as `[C:\Folder1\Folder2\textfile.csv] as tb1`

Comment: @cyboashu ok, and what path should i specify in the Connection string Data Source?

Comment: Maybe try something like @L42 's answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723206/vba-import-two-txt-files-in-the-same-workbook

Comment: Connection string can stay the same, everytime where You want to connect with another file just put what @cyboashu said. If anybody will not post an answer I will tomorow show You example how to do this. Edit: very good example in link given by above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work and was also able to resolve the **Power Query FROWN Error issue** (listing below).

> See the syntax of enclosing the filepath using `back-ticks`. Also the
>   **INNER JOIN** gets replaced with a "," and the **ON** gets replaced with a
>   **WHERE** Clause.

**Listing the steps i took:**

1. Removed all Power Queries in Excel workbook.
2. Installed latest Office.
3. 2016 Sept 3 updates from the following MS site. Rebooted my System.
4. Used **Microsoft Access Text Driver**. You can also use **ADO ACE.OLEDB.12** but follow the same syntax **for CSV files**.

The 2nd AND / OR the 3rd point may have resolved the issue, as i cannot see it is documented on MS site (my trial & error).

**For those who may face the same issue:**

the SQL QUERY SYNTAX is as shown in the below code. I was also able to use this same SYNTAX with **ACE.OLEDB.12 Driver** and it works fast and fine in both cases.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim oCon        As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRs         As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql      As String
    Dim strCon      As String

    strCon = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"

    strSql = "SELECT n.*,a.[Address] "
    strSql = strSql & " FROM `C:\Users\adam\Downloads`\Names.csv n"
    strSql = strSql & ","
    strSql = strSql & "`C:\Users\adam\Documents\TEST FOLDER`\Address.csv a"
    strSql = strSql & " WHERE n.Name= a.Name"

    oCon.Open strCon
    Set oRs = Nothing
    Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSql)

'    Sheet1.UsedRange.EntireRow.Delete
'    Sheet1.Cells(1).CopyFromRecordset oRs

    Dim oQT As QueryTable
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each oQT In Sheet1.QueryTables
        oQT.Delete
    Next oQT

    Sheet1.ListObjects(1).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set oQT = Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcQuery, oRs, Destination:=Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)).QueryTable
    With oQT
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
    End With


   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the example code using two separate files in one query.

Address.csv

```
Name,Address
Bruce,Dayton
Tony,10880 Malibu Point
Peter,20 Ingram Street
```

Names.csv

```
Name,Age
Bruce,49
Tony,48
Peter,28
```

Will return:

---

[image]

```
Sub test()

    Dim oCon        As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRs         As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql      As String
    Dim strCon      As String

    strCon = "DBQ=C:\;Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};MaxScanRows=8;"

    '/ Update file paths accordingly
    strSql = "Select n.*, a.[Address] " & _
            "From C:\Folder\With\File\containing\Names.csv n " & _
            "INNER JOIN C:\Folder\With\File\containing\Address.csv a " & _
            "ON n.Name = a.Name "

    oCon.Open strCon

    Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSql)

    Sheet1.UsedRange.EntireRow.Delete
    Sheet1.Cells(1).CopyFromRecordset oRs

End Sub
```

Comment: i am using `strSQL1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [" & strSht1 & "$] IN '" & strDataSource &"\" & strF1 & "'[" & "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited""" & "]"`

and for Connection, `oCN.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""` ...and similarly for File strF2....but getting an error - "filename and path not valid". Do i need to change to the above MS Text Driver provider?

Comment: `strSQL1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " & strDataSource & strF1
    oConstr = "DBQ=C:\;Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};MaxScanRows=8;"
    oCN.Open oConstr` '----- error here 

Getting error `"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"`

Comment: hi, in your question, you asked about CSV files. Now you are using a Wokbook example. Are you actually doing something or just randomly copy pasting text from net :)

Comment: I was using ACE.OLEDB to pull single csv files from different network folders. Then i realized i had to join some of the csv files to get a resultant recordset. Thats when the need arose to know how to add the different datasource paths for the csv files.

Comment: About the drive, you can check if it exists or not (it should as the text driver is part of standard build) in the ODBC tool. Search odbcad.exe, open the application, click  Add. In the next screen you will see all the drivers installed on the machine.

Comment: It says `"Windows cannot find 'odbcad.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."` I am using Windows 10 Enterprise edition, 64-bit and Excel 2016 Pro. Does that help?

Comment: Can the above be possible with ACE.OLEDB?

Comment: this works now - `oConstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "' ;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"";"
oCN.Open oConstr`........but this doesn't - `strSQL1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [" & strSht1 & "$] IN '" & strDataSource & strF1 & "'" & "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;""] "` .....gives a new error `External Table is not in the expected format.`

Comment: Finally after a lot of troubleshooting and after receiving different errors, i had to open registry and edit permissions on `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI` and then use `strCon = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"`. Now it works only if there are no spaces in the csv source paths.